# Difference between Math.Floor() and Math.Truncate() in .Net

Tags: c#, .net

What is the difference between Math.Floor() and Math.Truncate() in .NET?

e.g. Math.Floor(5.4) = 5 Math.Truncate(5.4) = 5 – subramani

Comment: Have you looked up the methods, what did you find.

Comment: Try the same exercise with `-5.4`.

Comment: @NikNek Be aware that the duplicate I assigned was **presented to you** when you created the question.

Comment: @mjwills the OP even copied a comment from that duplicate, see the "subramani"

Answer (score 0):

`Floor(-2.1)` will result in `-3`,
while `Truncate(-2.1)` will result in `-2`.

`Truncate` "cuts" off after the decimal point.
`Floor` on the other hand is a mathematical function that rounds **downwards** to the nearest integer.

Comment: You answer only tells the OP what the output of those functions will be, not why it is that those functions output those values. Consider editing your answer to give OP insight into why the outputs of the functions differ.